# Mock datarepository returns null Spring

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, junit

In my unit test im trying to test a service that add domains to a repository and after that i would ask the repository if the new domain exists. My service looks like:

```
public class DomainService {

@Autowired
private DomainRepository  domainRepository;

public Domain findOne(int id) {

    Domain domain = domainRepository.findOne(1);

    return domain;

}
}
```

I would write a unittest for this service:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DomainServiceTests {

@InjectMocks
private DomainService domainService;

@Mock
private DomainRepository domains;

@Test
public void Test() {

    Domain domain1 = new Domain("PHP", "Scripting language", "http://www.google.com");
    domains.save(domain1);

    when(domainService.findOne(domain1.getId())).thenReturn(domain1);


}
```

}

This throws a NullPointerException on the last line with the `domain1.getId()` call. What is the problem here? The `domains.save(domain1)` gives no error what suggests that the new domain is saved in the repository?

Comment: Are you sure it's that line and not the next line?  (That would require either `domains` or `domain1` to be `null`, which seems impossible.)  Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: You need to tell the mock what to return otherwise the default will to return null using `when` https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.13.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#stubbing. Its not obvious to me though what you're attempting to test in this scenario with the mock

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth right, edited the question.

Comment: @SeanCarroll i have a service called FindAllDomains witch find all the domains in the repository and returns that to the service. I would test that with a unitest...

Comment: I dont see your DomainService being used in what you have provided in your question. At the moment mocking your DomainRepository will just test that the mocking works and it will not provide you any information as to whether your actual code functions correctly. If you want to test your repository directly I dont believe mocking is the way to go. Write a test that goes against an actual db to verify its correctness.

Comment: Clarify the question

Comment: @Janp95, can you provide what specifically is causing the null pointer? Is it domainService? Can you provide the code for DomainService?